# i am using Data Tables ajax , but pagination , search bar, length menu not working

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

I am using Data Table AJAX, get data from JSON, data table pagination, search bar not working. This is my code.Get data from (progress_play_transactions.php) file in JSON

progress_play_transactions.php (code)

```
$data[] = array(
    "OriginalTransactionID" => "$OriginalTransactionID",
    "PlayerID" => "$PlayerID",
    "CasinoName" => "$CasinoName",
    "TransactionDate" => "$TransactionDate",
    "TransactionType" => "$TransactionType",
    "Currency" => "$Currency",
    "CurrencySymbol" => "$CurrencySymbol",
    "TransactionOriginalAmount" => "$TransactionOriginalAmount",
    "TransactionDetails" => "$TransactionDetails",
    "Status" => "$Status"
    );}
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$data,
        "recordsTotal" => intval( $totalrecords ),  
        "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalrecords)
    )
);
```

progress_play.php (code)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#examples').DataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "progress_play_transactions.php",
            "type": "json",
            "dataSrc": "result"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "OriginalTransactionID" },
            { "data": "PlayerID" },
            { "data": "CasinoName" },
            { "data": "TransactionDate" },
            { "data": "TransactionType" },
            { "data": "Currency" },
            { "data": "CurrencySymbol" },
            { "data": "TransactionOriginalAmount" },
            { "data": "TransactionDetails" },
            { "data": "Status" }
        ],
    });
});
```

Comment: please consider formatting the code.. let us know what you can see in console..

Comment: I edited to format code. Looks like some missing brackets and braces or too many.